# Regex expression to only get text not between tags

Tags: php, html, regex, text, replace

I'm trying to create a regex expression that will not get me text between a `<h1> </h1>` tag. I managed to create an expression for getting the text between the tags, but that's the opposite of what I'm going for. Any help would be appreciated!

Example:
`<h1> Don't include here </h1> Include this part` should give `Include this part`

Answer (score 0):

Is regex the right tool here? If you really need to extract data from HTML, consider using a proper HTML parser. PHP's built-in [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) has support for parsing HTML.

```php
$document=DOMDocument::loadHtml($yourHtml); //Parse the HTML
$headings=$document->getElementByTagName("h1"); //Find all H1's
foreach($headings as $heading)
    $document->removeChild($heading); //Remove all H1's
$remainingText=$document->textContent; //Remaining text after H1's have been removed
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I sort of need to use regex for this specific application

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that will grab any text outside of **any tag**, I'm not familiar enough with regex to make this specific to a `<h1>` tag, but this might work for your use case?

```
[^<>]*(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)
```

[RegExr link](https://regexr.com/5794u)